# how to compare values in date table of date datatype using dax

Tags: powerbi, pivot-table, dax, business-intelligence, analysis

I'm creating an if condition in dax query in which if date column value satisfy condition like
IF( date[date] > 06/01/2019 , calculation ) then it take me to the condition.
the values in date column are in date type format and format is mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: use date[date] > date(year, month, day)

Comment: okay i'm gonna try it